# How to return 504 (gatewayTimeout) in WebApi

Tags: c#, .net, api, http, asp.net-web-api

In my company API (we use WebAPI 2) we want to return 504 (gateway timeout) when controller action takes to much time. Sometimes inside our WebAPI actions we cooperate with external company APIs, which not always work correctly, so it could be convinient for user.

I added entry in web.config, but it doesn't work.

```
<system.transactions>
    <defaultSettings timeout="00:00:10" />
</system.transactions>
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

timeout is set in number of seconds, and I Think you should use httpruntime executiontimeout instead of transaction timeout wich only affects the transactions within the request

```
<system.web>
   <httpRuntime executionTimeout="10" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: It not working. I read about thois setting there is also needed to set debug to false in compilation node. But it still not working

Comment: are you running on a server iis , or on a debug session with the built in server in Visual studio?

Comment: I use Visual Studio IIS Express